# How to validate schema with nullable properties in karate 1.4

Tags: karate

I'm updating tests from karate 0.9.5 to 1.4.1.  We have a lot of schema validation tests for objects with properties that can be null, but the tests are not working in the newer version of Karate.

Here's a very simplified example that works as expected when the sub property has content.

```
* def nested = {'name': '#string'}
* def schema = {'sub': '##(nested)'}
Then match {'sub': {'name': 'I am here'}} == schema
```

My understanding of the karate docs is that the ## on `nested` makes it an optional field, but when the sub property is `null` then this fails:

```
Then match {'sub': null} == '#(schema)'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I've also discovered that karate 1.4.1 interprets the null on the left side of the == as EOF.  Defining the response in a variable as in the accepted answer addresses that.

Comment: wrapping complex stuff in round brackets may work on the LHS. but yes, the convention is to do `* match actual == expected`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this behavior changed slightly. What to do is explained here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#remove-if-null

Let me know if this now works for you.

```
* def nested = {'name': '#string'}
* def schema = ({'sub': '##(nested)'})
* def response = { sub: { name: 123 } } 
* match response == schema
```

Comment: I think this might need to be duplicated or referenced in the documentation under schema validation as the current example does not reflect the change regarding adding ()s around objects that are nested.  I would have never thought to look at the remove if null section to address a schema issue where an object is not returned  - https://github.com/karatelabs/karate?tab=readme-ov-file#schema-validation - related post - https://stackoverflow.com/q/78109057/2048207