# empty array is failing although set as optional in schema validation ##(variable)

Tags: karate

We setup a test and schema validation, but when the array is empty, it fails although the field is marked as optional and we set `configure matchEachEmptyAllowed = true`.

Could this be due to the response come back with a carriage return in the array rather than just []?

Request/response for call to evaluate against schema

```
  Scenario: Scenario for endpoint
    * configure matchEachEmptyAllowed = true

    Given path 'v1/mduManagementProperties'
    When method GET
    Then status 200
    * match $ == schemaList.QueryOrgPropertiesResponse

Response
{
  "staffContacts": [
  ]
}


Resulting error:

* match $ == schemaList.QueryOrgPropertiesResponse
match failed: EQUALS
  $ | not equal | actual does not contain key - 'businessHours' (MAP:MAP)
  {"staffContacts":[]}
  {"staffContacts":"##[] schemaList.ContactItem","businessHours":{"Monday":"##[] schemaList.Time","Tuesday":"##[] schemaList.Time","Wednesday":"##[] schemaList.Time","Thursday":"##[] schemaList.Time","Friday":"##[] schemaList.Time","Saturday":"##[] schemaList.Time","Sunday":"##[] schemaList.Time"},"errorMessage":"##string","lastBusinessHoursModificationDate":"##string","lastContactConfirmationDate":"##string","result":"##string","txnId":"#regex[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}","timestamp":"#regex^[0-9]{4}-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]{1}T[0-2][0-9]{1}:[0-5][0-9]{1}:[0-5][0-9]{1}(\\.[0-9]{1,9})?(Z)?(-[0-2][0-9]{1}:[0-5][0-9]{1})?$","message":"##string","systemErrorCode":"##string","code":"##string","clientIp":"##string","sourcePort":"##string"}
```

Schema parts

```
Feature: List of response schemas for validation
  Scenario: Set Schemas
    * def QueryOrgPropertiesResponse =
    """
        {
        businessHours: '##(schemaList.BusinessHours)',
        errorMessage: '##string',
        lastBusinessHoursModificationDate: '##string',
        lastContactConfirmationDate: '##string',
        result: '##string',
        staffContacts: '##[] schemaList.ContactItem',
        txnId: '#(txnIdCheck)',
        timestamp: '#(timestampCheck)',
        message: '##string',
        systemErrorCode: '##string',
        code: '##string',
        clientIp: '##string',
        sourcePort: '##string'
        }
    """

    * def BusinessHours =
    """
        {
        Monday: '##[] schemaList.Time',
        Tuesday: '##[] schemaList.Time',
        Wednesday: '##[] schemaList.Time',
        Thursday: '##[] schemaList.Time',
        Friday: '##[] schemaList.Time',
        Saturday: '##[] schemaList.Time',
        Sunday: '##[] schemaList.Time'
        }
    """

    * def Time =
    """
        {
        start: '##string',
        end: '##string'
        }
    """

    * def ContactItem =
    """
        {
        staffContactId: '##string',
        firstName: '##string',
        lastName: '##string',
        phoneNumber: '##string',
        phoneType: '##string',
        email: '##string',
        extension: '##string',
        businessHoursPrimary: '##boolean',
        businessHoursAlternate: '##boolean',
        afterHoursPrimary: '##boolean',
        afterHoursAlternate: '##boolean'
        }
    """
```

The issue is businessHours should be an optional field #, but it appears to be getting evaluated as a required field.  Here is a sample response that shows the same error

```
    * def testresponse =
    """
    {
      staffContacts: [
        {
          staffContactId: "3C831CD4-1C73-41FA-B060-D143821EB795",
          firstName: "TACIEUOWUK",
          lastName: "DomainContact",
          phoneNumber: "8769587433",
          phoneType: "mobile",
          email: "AddContact@mailinator.com",
          extension: "1",
          businessHoursPrimary: true,
          businessHoursAlternate: false,
          afterHoursPrimary: false,
          afterHoursAlternate: false
        }
      ]
    }
    """
    * match testresponse == schemaList.QueryOrgPropertiesResponse



Error:
* match testresponse == schemaList.QueryOrgPropertiesResponse
match failed: EQUALS
  $ | not equal | actual does not contain key - 'businessHours' (MAP:MAP)
  {"staffContacts":[{"staffContactId":"3C831CD4-1C73-41FA-B060-D143821EB795","firstName":"TACIEUOWUK","lastName":"DomainContact","phoneNumber":"8769587433","phoneType":"mobile","email":"AddContact@mailinator.com","extension":"1","businessHoursPrimary":true,"businessHoursAlternate":false,"afterHoursPrimary":false,"afterHoursAlternate":false}]}
  {"staffContacts":"##[] schemaList.ContactItem","businessHours":{"Monday":"##[] schemaList.Time","Tuesday":"##[] schemaList.Time","Wednesday":"##[] schemaList.Time","Thursday":"##[] schemaList.Time","Friday":"##[] schemaList.Time","Saturday":"##[] schemaList.Time","Sunday":"##[] schemaList.Time"},"errorMessage":"##string","lastBusinessHoursModificationDate":"##string","lastContactConfirmationDate":"##string","result":"##string","txnId":"#regex[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}","timestamp":"#regex^[0-9]{4}-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]{1}T[0-2][0-9]{1}:[0-5][0-9]{1}:[0-5][0-9]{1}(\\.[0-9]{1,9})?(Z)?(-[0-2][0-9]{1}:[0-5][0-9]{1})?$","message":"##string","systemErrorCode":"##string","code":"##string","clientIp":"##string","sourcePort":"##string"}

or 

* match testresponse contains schemaList.QueryOrgPropertiesResponse
match failed: CONTAINS
  $ | actual does not contain expected | actual does not contain key - 'businessHours' (MAP:MAP)
```

Answer (score 0):

Look carefully at what you are trying to match. A big object vs one with only one key. Maybe all you need to do is this:

```
 * match response contains schemaList.QueryOrgPropertiesResponse
```

EDIT - also see this, it most likely is the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78018894/143475

Comment: contains returns the same error `match failed: EQUALS
  $ | not equal | actual does not contain key - 'businessHours' (MAP:MAP)
  {"staffContacts":[]}
  {"staffContacts":"##[] schemaList.ContactItem","businessHours":...`

Comment: added sample response for schema check bu still getting failure for optional businessHours field not being present

Comment: @mike like many times before your example is too complicated. hopefully someone else here has time to look over it, but I can't. all the best. a reminder - this is what is expected: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The example I posted is a schema validation and response...unsure what is so complicated about that.

Comment: The new edit and related post resolved the issue by adding the ()s around the schema definitions which have nested objects and now returns the expected error for required txnid missing and no longer returns the error for business hours - `match failed: EQUALS
  $ | not equal | actual does not contain key - 'txnId' (MAP:MAP)
  {"staffContacts":[]}`