# karate : Complex JSON Schema matching , is it ok the validation schema of the responsebody?

Tags: arrays, json, karate

```
{
"id": 5,
"category": {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "string"
},
"name": "doggie",
"photoUrls": [
    "string"
],
"tags": [
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "string"
    }
],
"status": "string"
```

}
Scenario:
* def json =
"""
{
"id": 5,
"category": {
"id": 0,
"name": "string"
},
"name": "doggie",
"photoUrls": [
"string"
],
"tags": [
{
"id": 0,
"name": "string"
}
],
"status": "string"
}
"""

```
* def tags = { id: '#integer', name: '#string'}
* def photoUrls = { string: '#string' }
* def category = { id: '#integer',name: '#string'}


* def MYinternalDetails =
"""
  {
    id: '#string',
    name: '#string'
    status: '#string'
    textfield: '##[] textfield',
    tags: '##[] tags',
    photoUrls: '##[] photoUrls',
    category: '##{} category',


  }
"""
* match json == '#[] MYinternalDetails'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dhjga.png)

Comment: appear an issue when i run the feature , reference with tha matching structure
what is the correct validation schema of that json?

Comment: please edit your question to be simpler, don't just dump your existing JSON here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - maybe you ran into this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78018894/143475

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: tha issue is located  in the link above